# VS Code debugger won't start for asm code on Raspberry 4: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi, gdb, vscode-debugger

I want to do some assembly programming on my RPi 4 and I have a really hard time to get VS Code working.

I tried VSCode and C/C++ code will allow me to do debugging out of the box but assembly don't.

I created a Makefile:

```
build: test.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-ld test.o -o test

test.o: test.asm
    aarch64-linux-gnu-as test.asm -o test.o

clean: 
    rm *.o
    rm test
```

And that lead at least to that point that VS Code start gdb but in the Terminal I get:

```
GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted
```